# Do I have the wrong idea about PHP inheritance?

Tags: php, oop

I'm trying to create a simple example php script, there is a user class and then two controllers.

Imagine it as an MVC with no view.

At the moment I cannot get `getUserId()` to work within `showUserId()` in `usercontroller`, what am I doing wrong?

**PHP**

```
<?
class user{

    function getUserId(){

        return 1; //Simple Example
    }
}

class controller{

    function __construct(){

        $user = new User();
    }
}

class usercontroller extends controller{

    function __construct(){

        $user = new User();
    }

    function showUserId() {

        echo $user->getUserId();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: you should define $user as a property: `public $user;` then your constructor should be `$this->user = new User();`

Comment: ... and subsequently `$this->user->getUserId()`

Comment: This is an easy mistake to make if you're coming from a Java or C++ background.

Comment: Why would `controller` need to know about a user object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class usercontroller extends controller{

    private $user;

    function __construct(){

        $this->user = new User();
    }

    function showUserId() {

        echo $this->user->getUserId();
    }
}
```

You need to define the $user as class attribute of the controller class, define it in constructor, then you can use it in all functions..

Edit;

Yes you can define in oarent and call parent's constructor in child constructor, and use it..

```
<?
class user{   
    function getUserId(){    
        return 1; //Simple Example
    }
}

class controller{
    protected $user;
    function __construct(){    
        $this->user = new User();
    }
}

class usercontroller extends controller{

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        //$user = new User();
    }

    function showUserId() {    
        echo $this->user->getUserId();
    }
}

$controller_instance = new usercontroller();
$controller_instance->showUserId();    
?>
```

Comment: private visibility would be better here.

Comment: yeah..you are right..one don't want to have direct access to vars, have getters, setters..

Comment: Is it possible to declare the `private $user;` in controller and then access it in usercontoller?

Comment: Actually ... Silver89 brings up a good point; it should be defined inside `controller` and set to protected in that case.

Comment: Would you need to use `parent::__construct();` ? Surely the parent is always constructed?

Answer (score 1):

`$user` is only available in the `__construct` scope.  To be available in the object scope it has to be bound to the object as a member:

```
$this->user = new User;
```

Then, you can access `$this->user`.

It is also recommended to include this member as part of the class definition not only for clarity but also to set the correct access modifier.

Answer (score 1):

In your code example, $user exists as a local variable in the __construct() function.

If you want it to be a part of the class first define a class property with that name, then you can reference it by using the $this-> syntax.

```
class usercontroller extends controller {
    public $user;

    function __construct(){
        $this->user = new User();
    }

    function showUserId() {
        echo $this->user->getUserId();
    }
}
```

As a nit picky side note, your 'User' class is defined as 'user' in your code example.  I'm sure you intended those to match as you weren't asking about parse errors with your script.

Comment: private visibility would be better here.

Answer (score 1):

I would take out the `$user` variable from `controller`, because I don't feel it really belongs there:

```
class controller
{
}
```

Then, inside `usercontroller` I would pass a user object as a dependency:

```
class usercontroller extends controller
{
    private $user;

    function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function showUserId() 
    {
        echo $this->user->getUserId();
    }
}

$c = new usercontroller(new User());
echo $c->showUserId();
```

Comment: What's the reason behind using `public function showUserId()` rather than calling `echo $this->user->getUserId();` directly?

Comment: @Silver89 Calling it directly from where?

Comment: @Silver89 Regarding the updated question (that you later removed), the user must be passed into the model's constructor.

Comment: that tweaked with me after a good half an hour of looking over the code, thanks for the help!